# How to use while loop in bash

Tags: bash

New to bash
I was trying to write simple while loop:

```
let i = $1
while(i < 4); do
   echo Hi
   ((i++))
   done
```

Running this with: `$ bash bash_file.sh 0`
Gave me this warning
`bash_file.sh line 2: 4: no such file or directory`

Question: since when a variable must be file or directory?
How to solve this?

**EDIT**:  if I want to loop while i < $1 + $2, when $1 and $2 are numbers, how to write it>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an arithmetic statement (two parentheses), not a subshell. `let` is unnecessary here.

```
i=$1
while (( i < 4 )); do
...
done
```

`while`'s argument is a shell command. `( i < 4 )` starts a subshell which runs the command `i`, reading input from a file named `4`. The redirection is processed before the command is looked up, which explains why you don't get a `i: command not found` error.

You can simply replace `4` with the expression you want to use:

```
while (( i < $1 + $2 )); do
```

Comment: `let is unnecessary here.` You are using let... `(( i < 4 ))`

Comment: @ikegami: Great, now if I want to loop while i < $1 + $2, when $1 and $2 are numbers

Comment: The `let i=$1` is unnecessary; `((...))` is basically the same as `let`, but as a distinct syntactic structure it can be parsed differently (no need to quote `*` or whitespace, for instance).

Answer (score 4):

```
i=$1
while [ "$i" -le 4 ]
do
    echo $i
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

More about bash conditions:
https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/conditions-in-bash-scripting-if-statements/